# Why no constraint violations found using javax.validation.Validator? When object not populated with values

Tags: java, validation, junit, constraints, hibernate-validator

`multi-tenant-database-config-invalid-no-schema.yml`:

```
tenants:
  "001":
    tenantId: "001"
    configuration:
      database:
        url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=001"
        username: "postgres"
```

J-Unit class:

```
public class AppTest {

  @Test
  public void testInvalid() throws Exception {

    Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

    File multiTenantConfigurationFile = getMultiTenantTestConfiguration("config/multi-tenant-database-config-invalid-no-schema.yml");

    DatabaseEnabledTenants databaseEnabledTenants = objectMapper.readValue(multiTenantConfigurationFile, DatabaseEnabledTenants.class);

    Set<ConstraintViolation<DatabaseEnabledTenants>> constraintViolations = validator
            .validate(databaseEnabledTenants);
    Assertions.assertEquals(0, constraintViolations.size()); // <- Expect this to fail!
  }

  private File getMultiTenantTestConfiguration(String filename) throws URISyntaxException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    URL resource = classLoader.getResource(filename);
    File file = new File(resource.toURI());
    return file;
  }
}
```

`DatabaseEnabledTenants.java`:

```
@Valid
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "multi-tenancy")
public class DatabaseEnabledTenants {

  @Valid
  @NotNull private Map<String, DatabaseEnabledTenant> tenants = new HashMap<>();

  public Map<String, DatabaseEnabledTenant> getTenants() {
    return tenants;
  }

  public void setTenants(Map<String, DatabaseEnabledTenant> tenants) {
    this.tenants = tenants;
  }
}
```

`DatabaseEnabledTenant.java`:

```
@Valid
public class DatabaseEnabledTenant extends TenantDetails {

  @Valid
  @NotNull private Configuration configuration;

  /** Empty constructor, values populated later. */
  public DatabaseEnabledTenant() {}

  public Configuration getConfiguration() {
    return configuration;
  }

  public void setConfiguration(Configuration configuration) {
    this.configuration = configuration;
  }
}
```

`Configuration.java`:

```
public class Configuration {

  @NotNull private Database database;

  public Configuration() {}

  public Database getDatabase() {
    return database;
  }

  public void setDatabase(Database database) {
    this.database = database;
  }
}
```

`Database.java`:

```
public class Database {

  @JsonProperty("url")
  @NotBlank(message = "RL must not be blank in tenant configuration")
  @SchemaNameInJdbcUrlConstraint
  private String jdbcUrl;

  @NotBlank(message = "Database username must not be blank in tenant configuration")
  private String username;

  @NotNull(message = "Database password must not be null in tenant configuration")
  private String password;

  public Database() {}

  public String getUrl() {
    return url;
  }

  public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
  }

  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }
}
```

Comment: Answer: The validation doesn't fail because you have stated a schema in the JDBC url despite your intention to miss this out (Cf. `multi-tenant-database-config-invalid-no-schema.yml`). As a result `@SchemaNameInJdbcUrlConstraint` was satisfied.

Comment: @kladderradatsch but `password` is `null`

Comment: Did you forget a `@Valid` above `@NotNull private Database database;` in `Configuration.java`?